# Passing string to function which accepts pointer to char

Tags: c++, openssl

I've been working with OpenSSL library in C for a long time, but now I need to migrate to C++. OpenSSL's docs describe MD5 function like this.

```
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n,
              unsigned char *md);
```

I want to pass variable of type `string` to that function, but it accepts only `char *`.
*Is it possible to pass `string` to parameter of type `char *` directly in C++?* (I don't want to use extra manipulation with variable of type `string`)

Comment: note, if you're porting C code that is well written, there's no need to "C++-ify" it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `c_str` member function that `std::string` sports. Example

```
std::string data;
// load data somehow
unsigned char md[16] = { };
unsigned char *ret = MD5(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data.c_str()),
                         data.size(),
                         md);
```

If you want to do away with the ugly cast operator, define a string class that holds `unsigned char`s instead of `char`s and use that.

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;
ustring data;
unsigned char *ret = MD5(data.c_str(), data.size(), md);
```

Comment: I know, but it would be a slight loss of time, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ForceBru Where do you think that "loss of time" would come from?

Comment: @Angew, it might come from `c_str()` call, but it's ok if it wouldn't.

Comment: @ForceBru 1. any optimiser worth that name will inline the call; 2. if your situation is *so* time-critical that you're rightfully concerned about the potential performance hit of one non-virtual function call, don't trust anyone on the Internet and measure. Or just code in assembly.

Comment: @ForceBru: Since C++11, data() and c_str() perform the same function. [data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) returns pointer to the underlying array serving as character storage, so it's just returning a pointer and no copying business. You're, perhaps, worrying unnecessarily. Both functions have constant complexity.

Comment: I'd probably use `data.data()` rather than `data.c_str()`. Especially if there's a chance its not an ASCII string (maybe it holds binary data). Or use a `vector` as Richard suggests.

Answer (score 2):

just a little note, which may save you a headache later on. MD5 takes an unsigned char pointer as a parameter. This is a clue that it's actually not a string, but a pointer to bytes.

In your program if you start storing byte vectors in a std::string, you're eventually going to initialise a string with a byte vector containing a zero, which opens the possibility of a bug that's difficult to detect down the line.

It is safer to store all your byte vectors in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` (or `std::vector<uint8_t>` because this forces safe initialisation.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> plaintext;
// initialise plaintext here
std::vector<unsigned char> my_hash(16);
MD5(plaintext.data(), plaintext.size(), &my_hash[0]);
```